# Sparql: Counting the number of occurrences of a specific string/charater/diacritic in text using owlready2

Tags: regex, replace, sparql, find-occurrences, owlready

I have an ontology in an 'owl' file (quran_data_full.owl) and I saved it in a folder in my google drive (Quran Corpus). To perform some queries in this ontology, first I tried the query on Apache Jena Fuseki. It gave me the correct results so I copied the query into my code in google collab but unfortunately it gives an error as one function in the query was not supported by owlready2.

I wrote a query to search for a verse that contains a specific text and count any characters or even any diacritics in that verse.

This is my code in google collab:

```
from owlready2 import *
onto_path.append("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus")
go = get_ontology("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/quran_data_full.owl").load()
obo = get_namespace("/gdrive/MyDrive/Quran Corpus/")
d = list(default_world.sparql("""
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX qur: <http://quranontology.com/Resource/>

SELECT ?textSimple ?cnt
WHERE {
?verse rdf:type qur:Verse.
?verse qur:DisplayText ?o.
?verse rdfs:label ?textSimple.
    
FILTER ((REGEX(STR(?textSimple), "قل هو الله أحد" ,"i"))).    
  filter(regex( str(?textSimple) ,"ه")) 
  bind(
    strlen(
        replace(
            replace(str(?textSimple), "ه", "#")
            , "[^#]", ""
        )
    ) as ?cnt) 
}
"""))
```

This is the output:

```
OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception
```

I read the documentation [here](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sparql.html) about the replace function, they mentioned the following:

> The following functions are supported by Owlready, but not standard:
> The SIMPLEREPLACE(a, b) function is a version of REPLACE() that does not support Regex. It works like Python or SQLite3 replace, and has better performances.

What are the possible alternatives to count every occurrence for any characters or symbols in owlready2 without using replace?

This is the result from running the query on Apache Jena Fuseki:

[image]

You can see the full content of quran_data_full.owl file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xLMYASvHkJt1aoVqxG7A7tpbA6RX6nok/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: if there is no function that allows for replacing any character but the given char via a regex, then I think you're lost. The only weird workaround would be to enumerate every character except the char you want to count and replace those by an empty string - but who wants to do this ... any reason for using owlready instead of rdflib directly if you're using Python?

Comment: by the way, the data is probably rather small, why not computing the text based stuff in Python directly? Or an a fulltext index or some more text-driven data structure?